# InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount not initialing address

Tags: c++, windows

I'm working on a source code not written by me that does something like that:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION CriticalSection;

if (!InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&CriticalSection,
    0x00000400))
    return;


printf("CriticalSection: %p\r\n", CriticalSection);
```

I always get success but 0xFFFFFFFF as address of CriticalSection

Maybe I'm not getting the thing, can anyone help?

I'm building with Visul Studio 2015, c++14 with these settings:

- Platform toolset Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)
- _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501;WIN32

Comment: This function always succeeds by definition. If you want to print the address of your critical section then that would be `printf("CriticalSection: %p\r\n", &CriticalSection);`. Not sure why you would want to do that however, it's never going to change.

Comment: I guess the question is why you are expecting something different to be printed? As far as I know a CRITCAL_SECTION is an opaque type, you aren't supposed to look inside. Why are you trying to print the content of a critical section? Do you have any evidence that its not working?

Comment: @john I've tried also as you say with printf("CriticalSection: %p - &CriticalSection: %p\r\n", CriticalSection, &CriticalSection); but output is the same: "CriticalSection: FFFFFFFF - & CriticalSection: FFFFFFFF". I think %p always prints the address

Comment: The previous version of that program built with Visual Studio 2010 compiled in C was outputting the address, I think the developer logged that info to know it worked. I don't think switching from C to C++ changes the behaviour of that function

Comment: `%p` prints an address but a critical section is not an address, so the behaviour of `printf("CriticalSection: %p - &CriticalSection: %p\r\n", CriticalSection, &CriticalSection);` is undefined, try `printf("CriticalSection: %p\r\n", &CriticalSection);` as I suggested.

Comment: When you use `printf` the arguments you supply must match the format string, otherwise the behaviour of printf is undefined (in C and C++). You are seeing strange results because your format string specifies an address but the value you supply is not an address.

Comment: `%p` does not verify the input. It **expects** a pointer value, which you aren't providing. The result is undefined. It's unlikely that you are experienced enough to fix the code. Get someone that is and have them take over.

Comment: But printing the address of a critical section tells you nothing. It's just a variable, it has an address, an `int` would be no different. The whole concept that you can somehow print a critical section to find out if it is OK is flawed. Critical sections are opaque objects.

Comment: Ok, so the fact that the previous version of the software built with VS2010 was giving this output actually means nothing?  Initialize() InitializeCriticalSection... apiRc=1, done. sioCs=047CE858
Initialize() InitializeCriticalSection... apiRc=1, done. reqRepoCs=0E80E198
Initialize() InitializeCriticalSection... apiRc=1, done. prtRepoCs=0E80E1C0
Initialize() InitializeCriticalSection... apiRc=1, done. getJstoreCodeCs=0E80E1E8   I've never used that function before, so excuse me if I don't get the thing

Comment: I would say so.

Comment: But as I said you haven't yet printed the address correctly. Why not try what I suggested and see if you're happy?

Comment: C++ allows for false positives to the question: "Is this a program?" The fact by itself that a C++ program compiles means virtually nothing. The fact by itself that a C++ program produces the desired output means virtually nothing either. You need to either stop using C++ or stop attributing undue meaning to either of those observations.